# Orchard CMS Transaction Errors

Tags: .net, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

We are consistently, randomly getting the following errors on our Orchard site. It seems most prevalent when quickly navigating between pages. There are no other errors in the logs, so I'm not sure how to track down the root cause. We're not doing anything special with ODBC or anything like that (which is what google brought up when searching for this error with regard to Orchard).

```
[TransactionException: The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction.]
   System.Transactions.TransactionState.EnlistVolatile(InternalTransaction tx, IEnlistmentNotification enlistmentNotification, EnlistmentOptions enlistmentOptions, Transaction atomicTransaction) +45
   System.Transactions.Transaction.EnlistVolatile(IEnlistmentNotification enlistmentNotification, EnlistmentOptions enlistmentOptions) +159
   NHibernate.Transaction.AdoNetWithDistributedTransactionFactory.EnlistInDistributedTransactionIfNeeded(ISessionImplementor session) +307
   NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.EnlistInAmbientTransactionIfNeeded() +24
   NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.CheckAndUpdateSessionStatus() +23
   NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.CreateCriteria(Type persistentClass) +95
   Orchard.ContentManagement.DefaultContentManager.GetManyImplementation(QueryHints hints, Action`2 predicate) in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\DefaultContentManager.cs:302
   Orchard.ContentManagement.DefaultContentManager.Get(Int32 id, VersionOptions options, QueryHints hints) in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\DefaultContentManager.cs:140
   Orchard.ContentManagement.ContentGetExtensions.Get(IContentManager manager, Int32 id, VersionOptions options, QueryHints hints) in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\ContentExtensions.cs:160
   Orchard.Core.Settings.Services.SiteService.GetSiteSettings() in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard.Web\Core\Settings\Services\SiteService.cs:46
   Orchard.Settings.CurrentSiteWorkContext.Get(String name) in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\Settings\CurrentSiteWorkContext.cs:13
   Orchard.Environment.<>c__DisplayClass7`1.<FindResolverForState>b__2(IWorkContextStateProvider wcsp) in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\Environment\WorkContextImplementation.cs:32
   System.Linq.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext() +69
   System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate) +179
   Orchard.Environment.WorkContextImplementation.FindResolverForState(String name) in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\Environment\WorkContextImplementation.cs:32
   System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory) +64
   Orchard.Environment.WorkContextImplementation.GetState(String name) in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\Environment\WorkContextImplementation.cs:27
   Orchard.WorkContext.get_CurrentSite() in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\WorkContext.cs:52
   Orchard.Widgets.Filters.WidgetFilter.OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext) +1222
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +41
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +22
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +257
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +22
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +257
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +22
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +187
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +346
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__19() +30
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +19
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +52
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +52
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +52
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   Orchard.Mvc.Routes.HttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\Mvc\Routes\ShellRoute.cs:162
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +875
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +234
```

and

```
[TransactionAbortedException: The transaction has aborted.]
   at System.Transactions.TransactionStateAborted.CreateAbortingClone(InternalTransaction tx)
   at System.Transactions.DependentTransaction..ctor(IsolationLevel isoLevel, InternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean blocking)
   at System.Transactions.Transaction.DependentClone(DependentCloneOption cloneOption)
   at System.Transactions.TransactionScope.SetCurrent(Transaction newCurrent)
   at System.Transactions.TransactionScope.PushScope()
   at System.Transactions.TransactionScope..ctor(TransactionScopeOption scopeOption, TransactionOptions transactionOptions)
   at Orchard.Data.TransactionManager.Orchard.Data.ITransactionManager.Demand() in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\Data\TransactionManager.cs:line 37
   at Orchard.Data.SessionLocator.For(Type entityType) in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\Data\SessionLocator.cs:line 31
   at Orchard.ContentManagement.DefaultContentManager.GetManyImplementation(QueryHints hints, Action`2 predicate) in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\DefaultContentManager.cs:line 301
   at Orchard.ContentManagement.DefaultContentManager.Get(Int32 id, VersionOptions options, QueryHints hints) in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\DefaultContentManager.cs:line 140
   at Orchard.ContentManagement.DefaultContentManager.Get(Int32 id, VersionOptions options) in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\DefaultContentManager.cs:line 111
   at Orchard.ContentManagement.DefaultContentManager.Get(Int32 id) in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\DefaultContentManager.cs:line 107
   at Orchard.Security.Providers.FormsAuthenticationService.GetAuthenticatedUser() in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\Security\Providers\FormsAuthenticationService.cs:line 94
   at Orchard.Security.CurrentUserWorkContext.<Get>b__0[T](WorkContext ctx) in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\Security\CurrentUserWorkContext.cs:line 13
   at Orchard.Environment.WorkContextImplementation.<>c__DisplayClass7`1.<FindResolverForState>b__5() in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\Environment\WorkContextImplementation.cs:line 37
   at Orchard.Environment.WorkContextImplementation.GetState[T](String name) in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\Environment\WorkContextImplementation.cs:line 28
   at Orchard.WorkContext.get_CurrentUser() in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\WorkContext.cs:line 60
   at Orchard.Security.Authorizer.Authorize(Permission permission, IContent content, LocalizedString message) in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\Security\Authorizer.cs:line 72
   at Orchard.Security.Authorizer.Authorize(Permission permission) in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\Security\Authorizer.cs:line 60
   at Orchard.Security.SecurityFilter.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\Security\SecurityFilter.cs:line 24
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAuthorizationFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__19()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at Orchard.Mvc.Routes.ShellRoute.HttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\Mvc\Routes\ShellRoute.cs:line 162
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

EDIT:

I also discovered the following error today in the logs...it sounds like some sort of multi-threading bug in Orchard.

```
[InvalidOperationException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.]
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ValidateConnectionForExecute(SqlCommand\ command)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ValidateConnectionForExecute(String\ method, SqlCommand command)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ValidateCommand(String method, Boolean\ async)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior,\ RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1\ completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior,\ RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior,\ String method)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader()
at NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteReader(IDbCommand cmd)
at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.GetResultSet(IDbCommand st, Boolean autoDiscoverTypes,\ Boolean callable, RowSelection selection, ISessionImplementor session)
at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQuery(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters\ queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies)
at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(ISessionImplementor\ session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies)
at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters\ queryParameters)

[GenericADOException: could not execute query [ select providerco0_.Id as Id45_,\ providerco0_.IsEnabled as IsEnabled45_, providerco0_.DisplayName as DisplayN3_45_,\ providerco0_.ProviderName as Provider4_45_, providerco0_.ProviderIdKey as Provider5_45_,\ providerco0_.ProviderSecret as Provider6_45_, providerco0_.ProviderIdentifier\ as Provider7_45_ from NGM_OpenAuthentication_ProviderConfigurationRecord providerco0_\ where providerco0_.ProviderName=@p0 ] Name:p1 - Value:Google [SQL: select\ providerco0_.Id as Id45_, providerco0_.IsEnabled as IsEnabled45_, providerco0_.DisplayName\ as DisplayN3_45_, providerco0_.ProviderName as Provider4_45_, providerco0_.ProviderIdKey\ as Provider5_45_, providerco0_.ProviderSecret as Provider6_45_, providerco0_.ProviderIdentifier\ as Provider7_45_ from NGM_OpenAuthentication_ProviderConfigurationRecord providerco0_\ where providerco0_.ProviderName=@p0]]
at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters\ queryParameters)
at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.ListIgnoreQueryCache(ISessionImplementor session,\ QueryParameters queryParameters)
at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.List(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters\ queryParameters, ISet`1 querySpaces, IType[] resultTypes)
at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.Loader.QueryLoader.List(ISessionImplementor session,\ QueryParameters queryParameters)
at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QueryTranslatorImpl.List(ISessionImplementor session,\ QueryParameters queryParameters)
at NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLQueryPlan.PerformList(QueryParameters queryParameters,\ ISessionImplementor session, IList results)
at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.List(IQueryExpression queryExpression, QueryParameters\ queryParameters, IList results)
at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.List(IQueryExpression queryExpression,\ QueryParameters parameters)
at NHibernate.Impl.ExpressionQueryImpl.List()
at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.ExecuteQuery(NhLinqExpression nhLinqExpression,\ IQuery query, NhLinqExpression nhQuery)
at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
at System.Linq.Queryable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
at Orchard.Data.Repository`1.Get(Expression`1 predicate) in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\Data\Repository.cs:line 91
at Orchard.Data.Repository`1.Orchard.Data.IRepository<T>.Get(Expression`1\ predicate) in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\Data\Repository.cs:line\ 60
at NGM.OpenAuthentication.Services.ProviderConfigurationService.Get(String\ providerName)
at NGM.OpenAuthentication.Services.OrchardOpenAuthClientProvider.GetClientData(String\ providerName)
at NGM.OpenAuthentication.Shapes.<Discover>b__3(IExternalAuthenticationClient\ client)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at NGM.OpenAuthentication.Shapes.Discover(ShapeTableBuilder builder)
at Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors.DefaultShapeTableManager.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetShapeTable>b__4(Meta`1\ bindingStrategy) in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Descriptors\DefaultShapeTableManager.cs:line 48
at Orchard.Caching.DefaultParallelCacheContext.<>c__DisplayClass5`2.<>c__DisplayClass7.<RunInParallel>b__1()\ in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\Caching\DefaultParallelCacheContext.cs:line\ 24
at Orchard.Caching.DefaultParallelCacheContext.TaskWithAcquireContext`1.Execute()\ in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\Caching\DefaultParallelCacheContext.cs:line\ 71
at Orchard.Caching.DefaultParallelCacheContext.<RunInParallel>b__2[T,TResult](ITask`1\ task) in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\Caching\DefaultParallelCacheContext.cs:line\ 30
at System.Linq.Parallel.SelectQueryOperator`2.SelectQueryOperatorResults.GetElement(Int32\ index)
at System.Linq.Parallel.QueryResults`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
at System.Linq.Parallel.ArrayMergeHelper`1.ToArrayElement(Int32 index)
at System.Linq.Parallel.ForAllOperator`1.ForAllEnumerator`1.MoveNext(TInput&\ currentElement, Int32& currentKey)
at System.Linq.Parallel.ForAllSpoolingTask`2.SpoolingWork()
at System.Linq.Parallel.SpoolingTaskBase.Work()
at System.Linq.Parallel.QueryTask.BaseWork(Object unused)
at System.Linq.Parallel.QueryTask.<.cctor>b__0(Object o)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

[AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.]
at System.Linq.Parallel.QueryTaskGroupState.QueryEnd(Boolean userInitiatedDispose)
at System.Linq.Parallel.SpoolingTask.SpoolForAll[TInputOutput,TIgnoreKey](QueryTaskGroupState\ groupState, PartitionedStream`2 partitions, TaskScheduler taskScheduler)
at System.Linq.Parallel.DefaultMergeHelper`2.System.Linq.Parallel.IMergeHelper<TInputOutput>.Execute()
at System.Linq.Parallel.MergeExecutor`1.Execute()
at System.Linq.Parallel.MergeExecutor`1.Execute[TKey](PartitionedStream`2\ partitions, Boolean ignoreOutput, ParallelMergeOptions options, TaskScheduler\ taskScheduler, Boolean isOrdered, CancellationState cancellationState, Int32 queryId)
at System.Linq.Parallel.PartitionedStreamMerger`1.Receive[TKey](PartitionedStream`2\ partitionedStream)
at System.Linq.Parallel.ForAllOperator`1.WrapPartitionedStream[TKey](PartitionedStream`2\ inputStream, IPartitionedStreamRecipient`1 recipient, Boolean preferStriping,\ QuerySettings settings)
at System.Linq.Parallel.UnaryQueryOperator`2.UnaryQueryOperatorResults.ChildResultsRecipient.Receive[TKey](PartitionedStream`2\ inputStream)
at System.Linq.Parallel.ScanQueryOperator`1.ScanEnumerableQueryOperatorResults.GivePartitionedStream(IPartitionedStreamRecipient`1\ recipient)
at System.Linq.Parallel.UnaryQueryOperator`2.UnaryQueryOperatorResults.GivePartitionedStream(IPartitionedStreamRecipient`1\ recipient)
at System.Linq.Parallel.QueryOperator`1.GetOpenedEnumerator(Nullable`1 mergeOptions,\ Boolean suppressOrder, Boolean forEffect, QuerySettings querySettings)
at System.Linq.Parallel.ForAllOperator`1.RunSynchronously()
at System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.ForAll[TSource](ParallelQuery`1 source,\ Action`1 action)
at System.Linq.Parallel.ArrayMergeHelper`1.Execute()
at System.Linq.Parallel.QueryOperator`1.ExecuteAndGetResultsAsArray()
at System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.ToArray[TSource](ParallelQuery`1 source)
at Orchard.Caching.DefaultParallelCacheContext.RunInParallel[T,TResult](IEnumerable`1\ source, Func`2 selector) in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\Caching\DefaultParallelCacheContext.cs:line 27
at Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors.DefaultShapeTableManager.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetShapeTable>b__3(AcquireContext`1\ x) in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Descriptors\DefaultShapeTableManager.cs:line 42
at Orchard.Caching.Cache`2.CreateEntry(TKey k, Func`2 acquire) in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\Caching\Cache.cs:line 57
at Orchard.Caching.Cache`2.AddEntry(TKey k, Func`2 acquire) in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\Caching\Cache.cs:line 27
at Orchard.Caching.Cache`2.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Get>b__0(TKey k) in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\Caching\Cache.cs:line 19
at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.AddOrUpdate(TKey key,\ Func`2 addValueFactory, Func`3 updateValueFactory)
at Orchard.Caching.Cache`2.Get(TKey key, Func`2 acquire) in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\Caching\Cache.cs:line 17
at Orchard.Caching.DefaultCacheManager.Get[TKey,TResult](TKey key, Func`2\ acquire) in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\Caching\DefaultCacheManager.cs:line\ 33
at Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors.DefaultShapeTableManager.GetShapeTable(String\ themeName) in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Descriptors\DefaultShapeTableManager.cs:line 39
```

UPDATE 2:
New stack trace:

```
[TransactionException: The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction.]
   System.Transactions.TransactionState.EnlistVolatile(InternalTransaction tx, IEnlistmentNotification enlistmentNotification, EnlistmentOptions enlistmentOptions, Transaction atomicTransaction) +53
   System.Transactions.Transaction.EnlistVolatile(IEnlistmentNotification enlistmentNotification, EnlistmentOptions enlistmentOptions) +281
   NHibernate.Transaction.AdoNetWithDistributedTransactionFactory.EnlistInDistributedTransactionIfNeeded(ISessionImplementor session) +469
   NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.FireLoad(LoadEvent event, LoadType loadType) +353
   NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Get(String entityName, Object id) +454
   NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Get(Type entityClass, Object id) +372
   NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Get(Object id) +389
   Orchard.Data.Repository`1.Get(Int32 id) in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\Data\Repository.cs:87
   Orchard.ContentManagement.Handlers.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Loading>b__0(TRecord prior) in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Handlers\StorageFilter.cs:54
   Orchard.ContentManagement.Utilities.LazyField`1.GetValue() in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Utilities\LazyField.cs:24
   Orchard.Users.Models.RegistrationSettingsPart.get_UsersCanRegister() +16
   ASP._Page_Modules_Orchard_Users_Views_LogOn_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Users\jeff_000\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\cabwithme.orchard\Modules\Orchard.Users\Views\LogOn.cshtml:4
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +280
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +126
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +196
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) +158
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors.ShapeTemplateStrategy.ShapeTemplateBindingStrategy.Render(ShapeDescriptor shapeDescriptor, DisplayContext displayContext, HarvestShapeInfo harvestShapeInfo, HarvestShapeHit harvestShapeHit) in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Descriptors\ShapeTemplateStrategy\ShapeTemplateBindingStrategy.cs:137
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors.ShapeTemplateStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass28.<Discover>b__15(DisplayContext displayContext) in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Descriptors\ShapeTemplateStrategy\ShapeTemplateBindingStrategy.cs:118
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors.<>c__DisplayClass5.<BoundAs>b__2(DisplayContext displayContext) in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Descriptors\ShapeAlterationBuilder.cs:55
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DefaultDisplayManager.Process(ShapeBinding shapeBinding, IShape shape, DisplayContext context) in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DefaultDisplayManager.cs:179
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DefaultDisplayManager.Execute(DisplayContext context) in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DefaultDisplayManager.cs:88
   Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DisplayHelper.ShapeExecute(Object shape) in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DisplayHelper.cs:71
   ClaySharp.<>c__DisplayClass16.<InvokeMember>b__13() in C:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Clay\src\ClaySharp\ClayBehaviorCollection.cs:29
   ClaySharp.ClayBehaviorCollection.Execute(Func`1 proceed, Func`3 linker) in C:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Clay\src\ClaySharp\ClayBehaviorCollection.cs:13
   ASP._Page_Core_Shapes_Views_ShapeResult_Display_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Users\jeff_000\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\cabwithme.orchard\Core\Shapes\Views\ShapeResult\Display.cshtml:1
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +280
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +126
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +196
   Orchard.Mvc.ViewEngines.ThemeAwareness.<>c__DisplayClass7.<FindView>b__5(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, IViewDataContainer viewDataContainer) in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\Mvc\ViewEngines\ThemeAwareness\LayoutAwareViewEngine.cs:60
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +378
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17() +33
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +854172
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +854172
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +854172
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +854172
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +854172
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +854172
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +854172
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +854172
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +854172
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +854172
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +854172

   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +606
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288
```

Comment: What kinds of modules do you have enabled?

Comment: The default ones. Plus CKEditor, NGM.OpenAuthentication, and a custom one. I'd consider disabling them, if it would help me track down the cause...but there is no info from Orchard on the underlying problem in the exception I'm getting...

Comment: There's been a lot of issues with using TransactionScope (vague exception messages, performance problems, MSDTC etc.). Since 1.7 (current 1.x branch) we'll use explicit NHibernate transactions only. This will make most of the problems go away as well as allow async scenarios. If you can upgrade, you should.

Comment: Also, I'm not using transaction scopes anywhere in my code base. Not sure about the other modules.

Comment: I believe at one point I was seeing similar issues with the OpenAuthentication module. Try disabling it and seeing if you still get the same errors.

Comment: any suggestions on how to resolve if that is in fact the problem?

Comment: Try downloading the latest source for that OpenAuth from the repository

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I had the same sort of issue with an Orchard site hosted on SQL Azure I deployed recently - intermittent transaction errors, not much to go against in the logs, etc.

What finally fixed it for me (and it may or may not work for you, but it's worth a shot) was **adding Enlist=false; to the connection string** (in settings.txt in App_Data/Sites/Default).

I came across this on [a blog post someone made about EntityFramework and SQL Azure](http://martynnorman.wordpress.com/2012/05/10/entityframewwork-and-sql-azure/) and figured it was worth a shot with NHibernate also.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like the OpenAuthentication module is performing some database work during a call to `NGM.OpenAuthentication.Shapes.Discover(ShapeTableBuilder builder)`. This method is called by Orchard in parallel when preparing the shape table for caching. So it may or may not be ran on a different thread than the request one. No database operations should **ever** happen there without suppressing the current `TransactionScope` first.

Orchard 1.6 (and earlier) uses an ambient transaction (`TransactionScope`) over the whole request (it starts and ends when request starts and ends). So there may (and will) be situations when the request thread finishes before the spawned thread. It's perfectly normal. But... if there's a database operation being performed on that thread - it will fail because the underlying transaction has already been finished.

It's not an Orchard bug, but a possible bug in the OpenAuthentication module so it would be best to contact its author. But first, try to grab the latest source code from the repository (Gallery module may be way outdated) and try to repro.

Comment: You're exactly correct. He fixed it in the latest of his source code. I see he moved the data access code inside the OnDisplay delegate. Thank you!

Comment: Actually he fixed it in a version just a few days after my previous pull.

Comment: Ok...so I'm making progress. I updated the code for the module...now I get another transaction error, but only on the LogOn page. I turned off just my code, attached to the work process and observed the underlying cause: The transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004D024). It looks like it's trying to escalate to DTC because it's making multiple SqlConnections or something. I'm on cloud hosting and can't use DTC. How can I stop Orchard from creating this ambient transaction?

Comment: My guess is that the only reason it's escalating to DTC is because Orchard is trying to open multiple concurrent SqlConnections inside the TransactionScope. There's only one DB in the mix here.