# Transaction issues with Orchard and SSL/ADFS modules

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

We're using Orchard 1.6 with the Secured Sockets Layer 1.2 module and the Authentication.Federated 0.2 module.  On many of the requests, we get various transaction errors.  Here's an example of one that keeps cropping up:

```
[TransactionAbortedException: The transaction has aborted.]
   System.Transactions.TransactionStateAborted.CreateAbortingClone(InternalTransaction tx) +17
   System.Transactions.DependentTransaction..ctor(IsolationLevel isoLevel, InternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean blocking) +205
   System.Transactions.Transaction.DependentClone(DependentCloneOption cloneOption) +208
   System.Transactions.TransactionScope.SetCurrent(Transaction newCurrent) +152
   System.Transactions.TransactionScope..ctor(TransactionScopeOption scopeOption, TransactionOptions transactionOptions) +994
   Orchard.Data.TransactionManager.Orchard.Data.ITransactionManager.Demand() in C:\Projects\MySite\src\Orchard\Data\TransactionManager.cs:37
   Orchard.Data.SessionLocator.For(Type entityType) in C:\Projects\MySite\src\Orchard\Data\SessionLocator.cs:31
   Orchard.ContentManagement.DefaultContentManager.GetManyImplementation(QueryHints hints, Action`2 predicate) in C:\Projects\MySite\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\DefaultContentManager.cs:301
   Orchard.ContentManagement.DefaultContentManager.Get(Int32 id, VersionOptions options, QueryHints hints) in C:\Projects\MySite\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\DefaultContentManager.cs:140
   Orchard.ContentManagement.DefaultContentManager.Get(Int32 id, VersionOptions options) in C:\Projects\MySite\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\DefaultContentManager.cs:111
   Orchard.ContentManagement.DefaultContentManager.Get(Int32 id) in C:\Projects\MySite\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\DefaultContentManager.cs:107
   Orchard.Security.Providers.FormsAuthenticationService.GetAuthenticatedUser() in C:\Projects\MySite\src\Orchard\Security\Providers\FormsAuthenticationService.cs:94
   Orchard.Security.CurrentUserWorkContext.<Get>b__0(WorkContext ctx) in C:\Projects\MySite\src\Orchard\Security\CurrentUserWorkContext.cs:13
   Orchard.Environment.<>c__DisplayClass5`1.<FindResolverForState>b__3() in C:\Projects\MySite\src\Orchard\Environment\WorkContextImplementation.cs:37
   Orchard.Environment.WorkContextImplementation.GetState(String name) in C:\Projects\MySite\src\Orchard\Environment\WorkContextImplementation.cs:28
   Orchard.WorkContext.get_CurrentUser() in C:\Projects\MySite\src\Orchard\WorkContext.cs:60
   Orchard.Security.Authorizer.Authorize(Permission permission, IContent content, LocalizedString message) in C:\Projects\MySite\src\Orchard\Security\Authorizer.cs:72
   Orchard.Security.Authorizer.Authorize(Permission permission) in C:\Projects\MySite\src\Orchard\Security\Authorizer.cs:60
   Orchard.Security.SecurityFilter.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) in C:\Projects\MySite\src\Orchard\Security\SecurityFilter.cs:24
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAuthorizationFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +156
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +854224
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__19() +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +65
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +51
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +51
   Orchard.Mvc.Routes.HttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) in C:\Projects\MySite\src\Orchard\Mvc\Routes\ShellRoute.cs:162
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +606
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16268287/orchard-cms-transaction-errors) seems to indicate that this is an issue with the ambient transactions and should hopefully get resolved in 1.7.  However, is there something we can do to address these issues in 1.6?

**EDIT**:  Here's another one we keep getting:

```
[InvalidOperationException: The connection object can not be enlisted in transaction scope.]
   System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.Enlist(Transaction tx) +199
   System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.Open() +403
   NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider.GetConnection() +238
   NHibernate.AdoNet.ConnectionManager.GetConnection() +95
   NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.Prepare(IDbCommand cmd) +43

[ADOException: While preparing SELECT this_.Id as Id248_3_, this_.Number as Number248_3_, this_.Published as Published248_3_, this_.Latest as Latest248_3_, this_.Data as Data248_3_, this_.ContentItemRecord_id as ContentI6_248_3_, contentite1_.Id as Id247_0_, contentite1_.Data as Data247_0_, contentite1_.ContentType_id as ContentT3_247_0_, sitesettin4_.Id as Id253_1_, sitesettin4_.SiteSalt as SiteSalt253_1_, sitesettin4_.SiteName as SiteName253_1_, sitesettin4_.SuperUser as SuperUser253_1_, sitesettin4_.PageTitleSeparator as PageTitl5_253_1_, sitesettin4_.HomePage as HomePage253_1_, sitesettin4_.SiteCulture as SiteCult7_253_1_, sitesettin4_.ResourceDebugMode as Resource8_253_1_, sitesettin4_.PageSize as PageSize253_1_, sitesettin4_.SiteTimeZone as SiteTim10_253_1_, contenttyp5_.Id as Id250_2_, contenttyp5_.Name as Name250_2_ FROM Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord this_ inner join Orchard_Framework_ContentItemRecord contentite1_ on this_.ContentItemRecord_id=contentite1_.Id left outer join Settings_SiteSettingsPartRecord sitesettin4_ on contentite1_.Id=sitesettin4_.Id left outer join Orchard_Framework_ContentTypeRecord contenttyp5_ on contentite1_.ContentType_id=contenttyp5_.Id WHERE contentite1_.Id = @p0 and this_.Published = @p1 ORDER BY GETDATE() OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @p2 ROWS ONLY an error occurred]
   NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.Prepare(IDbCommand cmd) +390
   NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteReader(IDbCommand cmd) +84
   NHibernate.Loader.Loader.GetResultSet(IDbCommand st, Boolean autoDiscoverTypes, Boolean callable, RowSelection selection, ISessionImplementor session) +600
   NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQuery(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies) +273
   NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies) +205
   NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters) +425
   NHibernate.Loader.Loader.ListIgnoreQueryCache(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters) +23
   NHibernate.Loader.Criteria.CriteriaLoader.List(ISessionImplementor session) +60
   NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.List(CriteriaImpl criteria, IList results) +1055
   NHibernate.Impl.CriteriaImpl.List(IList results) +63
   NHibernate.Impl.CriteriaImpl.List() +79
   Orchard.ContentManagement.DefaultContentManager.GetManyImplementation(QueryHints hints, Action`2 predicate) in C:\Projects\MySite\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\DefaultContentManager.cs:334
   Orchard.ContentManagement.DefaultContentManager.Get(Int32 id, VersionOptions options, QueryHints hints) in C:\Projects\MySite\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\DefaultContentManager.cs:140
   Orchard.ContentManagement.ContentGetExtensions.Get(IContentManager manager, Int32 id, VersionOptions options, QueryHints hints) in C:\Projects\MySite\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\ContentExtensions.cs:160
   Orchard.Core.Settings.Services.SiteService.GetSiteSettings() in C:\Projects\MySite\src\Orchard.Web\Core\Settings\Services\SiteService.cs:46
   Orchard.Settings.CurrentSiteWorkContext.Get(String name) in C:\Projects\MySite\src\Orchard\Settings\CurrentSiteWorkContext.cs:13
   Orchard.Environment.<>c__DisplayClass5`1.<FindResolverForState>b__0(IWorkContextStateProvider wcsp) in C:\Projects\MySite\src\Orchard\Environment\WorkContextImplementation.cs:32
   System.Linq.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext() +82
   System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate) +215
   Orchard.Environment.WorkContextImplementation.FindResolverForState(String name) in C:\Projects\MySite\src\Orchard\Environment\WorkContextImplementation.cs:32
   System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory) +83
   Orchard.Environment.WorkContextImplementation.GetState(String name) in C:\Projects\MySite\src\Orchard\Environment\WorkContextImplementation.cs:27
   Orchard.WorkContext.get_CurrentSite() in C:\Projects\MySite\src\Orchard\WorkContext.cs:52
   Contrib.SecuredSocketsLayer.Filters.SecuredSocketsLayersFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) +231
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +72
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +854290
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +309
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +854224
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__19() +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +65
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +51
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +51
   Orchard.Mvc.Routes.HttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) in C:\Projects\MySite\src\Orchard\Mvc\Routes\ShellRoute.cs:162
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +606
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288
```

**EDIT2**:  Took the SSL module out of the mix by disabling it and am just accessing over SSL at all times.  (Doesn't solve the issue, but does show that this issue occurs with just the Auth.Fed module.)

**EDIT3**:  I tried putting suppression code around each method in the Auth.Fed module, but it didn't help.  (Causes issues on the Authenticate due to nested transactions, which made me think that might be where the issue was, but then I was able to reproduce before getting to that step, so doesn't seem to be it.)

Comment: Can you please verify with 1.7, so that we can make sure it's fixed?

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy:  How do I upgrade to 1.7? :)

Comment: If you have a Mercurial clone of the source, you update to 1.x (warning: this is unreleased code). Otherwise, you can download the source for the latest in 1.x from CodePlex and upgrade using that.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy:  Thanks; downloaded the source, but it looks like it's going to take me a bit to get it running (error right out of the gate).  Will let you know what I find.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy: Is there a set of instructions somewhere on how to get Orchard running when you download the source?

Comment: Well, just open src/orchard.sln from VS. http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Setting-up-a-source-enlistment

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy: `If you are not a developer on the Orchard project, you can download the source code, compile it and play with it, but you won't be able to submit changes other than by submitting patches.`  I get errors from a clean pull.  `Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'Orchard.Environment.DefaultOrchardShell' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'Orchard.Mvc.Routes.IRoutePublisher routePublisher' of constructor`

Comment: You shouldn't. Please describe the exact steps you followed.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy: 1) Go to Source Code tab on CodePlex. 2) Choose 1.x branch. 3) Click Download. 4) Unzip downloaded zip. 5) Open sln in VS2010. 6) Open Orchard.Web properties Web tab and set to virtual directory in IIS (`http://localhost/Orchard17`). 7) Build (F6). 8) Run (F5). 9) Receive error.

Comment: Make Orchard17 an application, not a plain vdir. Configure the app pool for .NET 4 or 4.5, full trust.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy:  It's called vdir in VS; it's an app in IIS.  The app pool is v4.0.  The app is running as full trust.

Comment: So you're saying that a plain download of the latest in 1.x, without modifications whatsoever, won't run on your machine? Can you give more details about your configuration?

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy:  That's correct.  I'm on 64-bit Win7 with .NET 1.1 and .NET 4.5 installed, running out of VS2010 (though actually in IIS).  Do you have specific questions?

Comment: Does it crash after setup or before setup?

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy:  Before setup.  The steps above are exactly what I do, from scratch.  It doesn't get to any sort of display.

Comment: And no compilation errors? (the class it's complaining about is in Orchard.Framework, which is loaded before pretty much anything else, so that it doesn't find it would indicate that you're missing something fundamental)

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy:  Just did a Rebuild Solution; 0 errors and 0 warnings.

Comment: Can you try it with the built-in VS web server?

Comment: Also, please grab the latest 1.x as some bugs that may cause this have been fixed this week.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy:  Cool, that worked.  However, in order to test, I need to be able to pull it up in IIS - need to be able to use SSL.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy:  Will grab and report.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy:  Same behavior.